# Do not expire artifacts in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file I am specifying that the artifacts expire in 1 day, however, from the gitlab website I can download the artifacts of each of the jobs that are older than two months and when I go to "usage quotas " shows that there is a lot of space used in the artifacts.

[Here is docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in)

How can I delete them?

This is a snippet of my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
build:
  stage: build  
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null || $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME =~ /^dev/ || $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME =~ /^hotfix/ || $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME =~ /^feature/ || $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME =~ /^error/'
  script:
    # - ...
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_NAME.tar.gz
```

Comment: I check the items where "Setting expire_in does not affect" according to the documentation?